# How to work out how much pulling power an electric motor has in kg?

Tags: power-electronics, converter, specifications

Say I have 5 kg mass on a spindle that has a diameter 5 cm and I want to move it up at 6 cm/s (just example numbers). How would I find out the specs needed for what electric motor I would need?

I have found a lot of info online but most things need info the motors stat sheet has not got and trying to get that info is just confusing me
here is an example motor... also why has it got some things 2 times? like "Current" and "Speed" [Standard (High Power) D.C. Motors 20000 RPM](http://www.jaycar.com.au/standard-high-power-d-c-motors-20000-rpm/p/YM2772)

Comment: Are you talking rotary motion, or linear motion?

Comment: The motor is going to have a torque rating on it. Figure out how much torque you need to hold 5kg on the end of a 2.5cm arm. Then add torque to get your desired acceleration. Ensure the motor can run fast enough by using PI * 5cm * rpm * min/60s to get the linear speed.

Comment: "need info the motors stat sheet has not got" - what info _has_ the motor stat sheet got?

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Click on the "Specifications" tab and you'll see the speed and current ratings explained. mg(dh/dt) gives you motor power, and mg*radius gives you torque, you want the motor/gearing combination to beat both of these plus a safety margin.

Comment: HOWEVER, 6V*13.5A = 81W but 320Nm*1437 radians/second is about 460kw, so the "specifications" are utter garbage. The non-SI units "0.32kg/cm" (should be kgf*cm) translates to 0.032Nm for 46W and about 60% efficiency. Compare that to the torque you need and you'll find the gearing you need.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical power required, in watts, is \$T\omega\$, where \$T\$ is torque in \$Nm\$ and \$\omega\$ is rotational speed in \$rad\:s^{-1}\$. You might need to double this power to arrive at the electrical motor power required in order to overcome friction losses in the gearbox or linkage and also to take into account motor losses.

In your case the mechanical power required is about \$3\:W\$.

Comment: so how do i convert that to something i can find on a motor stat sheet ?
i updated the post

Comment: The rotational speed of a 5cm diameter pulley will be approximately 20rpm so, with the example motor, you would need a 1000:1 reduction gearbox. Hence better to select a geared motor. Torque is often given in kg-cm and you already have this: 5kg x 2.5cm. Motor power, say, 10W to give factor of safety. I did the calcs over a bowl of cornflakes, so 'no guarantee' disclaimer applies!

Comment: I believe it's even simpler, no need to bring up torque and radiants to reckon power. \$P=Fv=mgv\approx 5\,\text{kg}\times 10\,\text{m s}^{-2}\times 0.06\,\text{m s}^{-1}=3\,\text{W}\$

Comment: Yes, that's neater!

Comment: @carloc: Don't you need to add in the acceleration of the load to the _g_ term?

Comment: @Transitor, oh yes you are quite right, that was just the steady state power ideally needed. Of course if you need to reach that speed in a finite time you need to add some.

Comment: how can you tell i will need a "1000:1 reduction gearbox"?

Comment: @Jesse: Add some calculations to your original post. What RPM do you need on the spindle? What is the likely optimum speed of your motor? The ratio between the two is your gearbox ratio.

Comment: any chance there is some sort of online converter around? something that i can just input the known things and it will work out the rest if possible

Comment: "You might need to double this power to arrive at the electrical motor power required in order to overcome friction losses in the gearbox or linkage and also to take into account motor losses."  This will often be specced.  If you need to know it, buy stuff that is specced.  In some cases, doubling won't even do the job!  I had a big lead-screw situation where just about the entire torque of the system was eaten up before even talking about the load.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really more of a classical mechanics question than a electrical engineering question.

Essentially, electric motors (and all rotational mechanical power generators) spin a shaft with a given speed and torque.

To make things perhaps a bit easier to understand, consider that the definition of Work (W) is Force * Displacement $$W=F s$$
Now, if we think in terms of rates of change, and divide both sides (in calculus terms read: differentiate) by time, we get an equation for power:
$$ P=Fv $$
wherein v is our velocity. 
What you might be wondering, however, is how to interpret this equation. For your numbers,  $$mass=5; diameter=5cm; v=6cm/s$$ we first calculate a needed power quantity (roughly approximating g=10m/s^2):
$$P = Fv=gmv=10*5*0.06=3W$$

Next, for the motor, you need to think in terms of ANGULAR velocity by converting your linear velocity (c is your circumference):
$$ \omega=v/r=2.4 rad/s $$

Using the analogous power equation for rotating systems that Chu gave you:
$$P=T\omega$$
we plug in our value for omega and P to get our desired T torque:

$$3=T*2.4 \rightarrow T=1.25Nm$$
So you need a motor capable of at least 1.25 Newton meters of torque (at your desired speed of 2.4/(2Pi)*60=23RPM) to be able to lift your mass ASSUMING a lossless system (bearings, etc frictionless).

Note: generally, motor manufacturers should provide a torque-speed curve that indicates the motor's maximum torque at a given speed. If your motor in question can deliver the power (the product of speed and torque) that you need but not at the correct speed, this is when you need a gearbox to change torque and speed to match your application. Do note that electrical motors exhibit different power outputs on different parts of the torque speed curve. The shape of the torque speed curve of the motor is also heavily dependent on the type of motor you are working with.